# How to fix the problem of not showing the sitemap in django?

Tags: django

I created a sitemap as follows, but nothing is displayed inside the sitemap URL.
How can I fix the problem?

Thank you

setting.py

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    ]
```

sitemaps.py

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from riposts.models import Posts

class RiSitemap(Sitemap):

    priority = 0.5
    changefreq = 'daily'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        posts = self.kwargs.get('posts')
        return Posts.objects.filter(status="p")

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.updated
        
    def location(self, item):
        return reverse(item)
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from .views import  home_page
from riposts.sitemaps import RiSitemap

sitemaps = {
    'posts':RiSitemap,
}

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_page, name="home"),
    path("sitemap.xml", sitemap, {"sitemaps": sitemaps}, name="sitemap"),
]
```

[sitemap image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hioPS.jpg)

Comment: Well, _are_ there any `Posts` objects with `status="p"`?

Comment: Yes,published posts default status are "p"

Comment: And you're absolutely, positively sure such objects do exist in the database?

Comment: Yes, there is a status of posts in the database